# 4 point persective transform failure

Tags: python, opencv

I've been trying to do a 4 point perspective transform in order to start doing some OCR.

Starting with the following image I can detect the number plate

[image]

and crop it out with the green box being the bounding box and the red dots being the corners of the rectangle I want to square up.

[image]

This is the output of the transform.

[image]

At a first look it seams to have done the transform inside out (taking the parts either side rather than between the points).

I'm using the imutils package to do the transform and working from [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/) and [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) as a guide. I'm sure it's something relatively simple I'm missing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils import contours
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform

img = cv2.imread("sample7-smaller.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,15,75,75)
v = np.median(blurred)
lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - 0.33) * v))
upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + 0.33) * v))
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, lower, upper, 255)

conts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
conts = conts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else conts[1]
conts = sorted(conts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for cnt in conts:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        for i in approx:
            cv2.circle(img,(i[0][0], i[0][1]),2,(0,0,255), thickness=4)
        warped = four_point_transform(img, approx.reshape(4,2))
        cv2.imshow("crop",img[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        cv2.imshow("warped", warped)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the OpenCV [Perspective Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform) method, to get the desired results, as per the given image:

[image]

First mark the position of src points:

```
src_pts = np.array([[8, 136], [415, 52], [420, 152], [14, 244]], dtype=np.float32)
```

And suppose you want to fit this number plate in a matrix of shape 50x200, so destination points would be:

```
dst_pts = np.array([[0, 0],   [200, 0],  [200, 50], [0, 50]], dtype=np.float32)
```

Find the perspective Transform Matrix as :

```
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)
warp = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (200, 50))
```

[image]

EDIT: As you didn't wanted to hard code the final width, height of plate, So in order to make the calculations more flexible you can calculate the width and height of the plate from the 4 marker points as:

```
def get_euler_distance(pt1, pt2):
    return ((pt1[0] - pt2[0])**2 + (pt1[1] - pt2[1])**2)**0.5

src_pts = np.array([[8, 136], [415, 52], [420, 152], [14, 244]], dtype=np.float32)

width = get_euler_distance(src_pts[0][0], src_pts[0][1])
height = get_euler_distance(src_pts[0][0], src_pts[0][3])

dst_pts = np.array([[0, 0],   [width, 0],  [width, height], [0, height]], dtype=np.float32)

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)
warp = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (width, height))
```

Comment: That's what the imutils code is supposed to be doing (http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/#crayon-58a578867d24b280571411), it looks to be doing the same thing, just calculating the dimensions of the output on the fly

Comment: So you want your output dimension to be be calculated on the fly @hardillb ?

Comment: I'd like to keep it at the same scale to start with, then I can rescale it later

Comment: unfortunately that's still giving the same output (and the values you're passing into the `get_euler_distance` need to be pairs not single values). I've zipped up all my code and the original image [here](http://www.hardill.me.uk/sample.tgz) if you want another look.

Comment: OK, I've finally worked out what the problem was, the version of imutils I have installed has a bug in it's `order_points` which was swapping the upper right and lower right hand corners of the area to be transformed.