# Manually performing perspective transformation on images using OpenCv for different types of images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am creating a dataset for `UNET` where I the Image I want to get as `Y` is a binarized image. I have written a code for `OpenCv` which uses input from users as sliding bars and saves the image after pressing given key.

**Could someone please Help me apply Perspective Transformation to different images. I can get the respective values from the `TrackBar` if needed.**

My images look something like this:

[image]

Below is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage.filters as filters
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


class InteractiveBinarization():
    def __init__(self,path='./images/',out='./out/'):
        '''
        args:
            path: Path of the directory which has all the images
            out: Path of directory where your binarized images will be saved
        '''
        self.path = path
        self.images = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
        self.N = len(self.images)
        self.out = out

    def dummy(self,x=None)->None:
        '''
        Does not do anything. Used to pass to crateTrackbar as it needs a function
        '''
        pass


    def binarize(self,window_width:int=350,window_height:int=350)->None:
        '''
        Method to binarize the Image based on the sliding values from the bars. It accepts Gauss Kernal, Sharpeen Amount, Sharpen Radius, Rotation Angle
        Press 'esc' or 'q' to quit, 's' to save the binarized image, 't' for printing the current bar values to image, 'p' for previous image and 'n' for next image
        args:
            window_width: Width of the Window which has sliding bars
            window_height: Height of window for the sliding bars
        '''
        cv2.namedWindow('Tracking Window',cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.resizeWindow('Tracking Window', window_width, window_height)
        
        cv2.createTrackbar('kernel','Tracking Window',3,513,self.dummy) # gauss kernal size
        cv2.createTrackbar('x_sigma','Tracking Window',0,100,self.dummy) # gauss X sigma
        cv2.createTrackbar('y_sigma','Tracking Window',0,100,self.dummy) # gauss Y sigma

        cv2.createTrackbar('amount1','Tracking Window',0,7,self.dummy) # sharpen amount number
        cv2.createTrackbar('amount2','Tracking Window',1,100,self.dummy) # sharpen amount decimal
        cv2.createTrackbar('radius1','Tracking Window',0,7,self.dummy) # sharpen radius
        cv2.createTrackbar('radius2','Tracking Window',1,100,self.dummy) #  sharpen radius decimal

        cv2.createTrackbar('angle','Tracking Window',0,360,self.dummy) # rotation angle

        QUIT = False
        put_text = False
        read_image = True
        counter = 0
        while not QUIT:

            if read_image:
                img_name = self.images[counter]
                img = cv2.imread(self.path+img_name)
                read_image = False

            g_k = cv2.getTrackbarPos('kernel','Tracking Window')
            if g_k % 2 == 0:
                g_k+=1

            g_x_sigma = cv2.getTrackbarPos('x_sigma','Tracking Window')
            g_y_sigma = cv2.getTrackbarPos('y_sigma','Tracking Window')

            s_a1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('amount1','Tracking Window') # 1,2,3,4
            s_a2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('amount2','Tracking Window') # .01, ..... 0.99
            s_r1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('radius1','Tracking Window') # same as above
            s_r2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('radius2','Tracking Window')
            s_a = round(s_a1 + s_a2/100,2) # 1.01.......... 7.99
            s_r = round(s_r1 + s_r2/100,2) # same asa above

            angle = cv2.getTrackbarPos('angle','Tracking Window')

            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (g_k,g_k), g_x_sigma,sigmaY=g_y_sigma)
            division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=255)
            sharp = filters.unsharp_mask(division, radius=s_r, amount=s_a, multichannel=False, preserve_range=False)
            sharp = (255*sharp).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

            kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
            opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
            closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

            thresh = cv2.threshold(sharp, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1]

            # rotate
            (h, w) = thresh.shape[:2]
            center = (w // 2, h // 2)
            M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1)
            thresh = cv2.warpAffine(thresh, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=255)

            if put_text:
                text = f"g_k: {g_k} , g_x_sigma: {g_x_sigma} , g_y_sigma: {g_y_sigma} , s_a: {s_a} , s_r: {s_r} , angle: {angle}"
                cv2.putText(thresh,text,org=(30,30),fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,fontScale=0.5,color=(0,128,0),thickness=1)

            cv2.imshow('Image', thresh)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1) # show for 1 miliseconds. Because the loop is infinite, it'll be infinitely showing the results
            if key==27 or key == ord('q'): # Press escape / q  to close all windows
                QUIT = True
                break

            elif key == ord('s'): # save binary image
                cv2.imwrite(self.out+'binary_'+img_name, thresh)

            elif key == ord('t'): # show or hide text on image
                put_text = not put_text

            elif key == ord('n'):
                if counter < self.N-1:
                    read_image = True
                    counter += 1

            elif key == ord('p'):
                if counter > 0: 
                    read_image = True
                    counter -= 1

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What values can we get from the trackbar? As in what behaviour do you want when the user slides the trackbar

Comment: I think the trackbar can get numerical values. That is why I have use 2 different variables for `s_a1,s_a2` so I can produce `1.2, 3.99` etc. What I want to ask is that how can I use `Perspective Transformation`. I have no idea how that'd work manually. I think there will be lot of coordinates as list of lists [given in this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perspective-transformation-python-opencv/)

Comment: Does this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42270581/3051961 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  But instead of manually passing in the points, I want to do it with `TrackBar`. How can I make the Trackbar select the points. I have to build a script for my Non Tech team actually so that they can select and apply the transformation. Maybe 4 trackbar are the coordinates of the image? Or crop or something else.